# Parsing data JSON and Python

Tags: python, json

```
import requests

url = "http://api.geonames.org/citiesJSON?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&lang=de&username=demo"
request = requests.get(url)
fetch_data = request.json()

print (request.content)

for item in fetch_data:
    print(item)
```

I am trying to fetch items within JSON Request `geonames -> lng`. If I make use of `item['lng']`

Then getting error

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

EXAMPLE of JSON Request

```
{  
   "geonames":[  
      {  
         "lng":-99.12766456604,
         "geonameId":3530597,
         "countrycode":"MX",
         "name":"Mexiko-Stadt",
         "fclName":"city, village,...",
         "toponymName":"Mexico City",
         "fcodeName":"capital of a political entity",
         "wikipedia":"en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexico_City",
         "lat":19.428472427036,
         "fcl":"P",
         "population":12294193,
         "fcode":"PPLC"
      }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You're iterating over the *dictionary* `fetch_data`, so `item` is the key (e.g. `'geonames'`), which is a string, as the error message tells you.

Comment: Use `for key, item in fetch_data.enumerate():`

Comment: @Barmar `'dict' object has no attribute 'enumerate'`...?

Comment: This code doesn't run... `the daily limit of 30000 credits for demo has been exceeded.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try;

```
for item in fetch_data['geonames']:
    print(item['lng'])
```